# Position middle container right after the one before, but docked to bottom

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, html, position

I have a web page that consists of a header, slider menu content and footer.

I need the content to start from the menu (menu size and location is based on the elements above that depends on device), and it should always be 25px from the bottom overlapping the footer.

If I try to make it relative, it hangs to the middle and doesn't reach the end, if I make it absolute, I have to specify the value it should be started from which is dynamic.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

**UPDATE**
I don't mind doing it with jQuery as long as the top of the content is dynamic and depends on the previous element no matter what it is.

**UPDATE**
[Here](http://goo.gl/E0zRuX)'s an abstract example to what I need.

The footer should always be anchored to the bottom (later I'll apply sticky footer technique, here my issue is the content), the header, slider and menu are anchored to element above, the content should be anchored to the element above and to the footer.

Comment: @NaveedButt working on it, but the question still remains.

Comment: @Shimmy how about pulling the _footer_ up and making the _main_ have the bigger `z-index`then _footer_ ? [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/NcpwC/)

Comment: @Vucko the footer in the example changes size. Also, I don't want to spceify size in the container, it has to be docked to top and bottom no matter what's inside.

Comment: @Shimmy what do you mean changes size ? Does the footer have fixed or dynamic size? It isn't clear in your question about the footer.

Comment: The footer has a fixed size

Comment: @Shimmy then what's wrong with my example ? Please explain better.

Comment: In your example, the footer's size is `100px`, however try shrinking the height of the display area and you'll see the footer is swallowed under the bottom. Check the [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/NcpwC/1/) fiddle.

Comment: You can use tables as well, set table height to 100% and set your footer and other content to specific heights. The browser will auto calculate the remaining space depending on screen size.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. [Here](http://www.levhm.com/) is a link to the website, I wanna change all the containers to `relative` except for `main-content` and `footer`. BTW, is there a way to extract a plain HTML+JS+CSS example from a page?

Comment: do you want the header to be fixed when you scroll the page? or to be scrolled like the content?

Comment: @avrahamcool only footer is fixed (in the future i will make it disappear when page is too short, but header, menu etc. aren't fixed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your not very clear with what you want exactly. so I've made some assumptions.
(all of those assumptions can be corrected if I assumed wrong).

**Assumptions:**

1. Header should scroll with the content. (that behavior can be changed if you want)
2. the scroll should be applied on the 'Content Zone' only. (that behavior can be changed if you want)
3. the content wrapper should always span to the end of the page, even if the physical content is smaller then that. and should have a scrolling only when the physical content is larger than the available space. (that behavior can be changed if you want)

[as you can see, all of those behaviors can be changed with the correct CSS]

Here is a [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/J9z9Q/)

1. this is a pure CSS solution. (I always avoid scripts if I can)
2. cross browser (*Tested on*: IE10, IE9, IE8, Chrome, FF)

**HTML:** (I've added a wrapper for the scroll-able content)

```
<div class="scollableContent">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>header</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque lacinia tempus diam in malesuada. Aliquam id enim nisl. Integer hendrerit adipiscing quam, fermentum pellentesque nisl. Integer consectetur hendrerit sapien nec vestibulum. Vestibulum ac diam in arcu feugiat fermentum nec id nibh. Proin id laoreet dui, quis accumsan nisi. Quisque eget sem ut arcu faucibus convallis. Sed sed nisl commodo, faucibus leo sed, egestas est. Cras at nibh et erat ullamcorper sollicitudin vitae non nibh.</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <h2>footer</h2>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.scollableContent
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 25px; /*.footer height*/
    overflow: auto;
}
.scollableContent:before
{
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.header
{
    /*Addition*/
    background-color: red;
}
.main
{
    /*Addition*/
    background-color: yellow;
}
    .main:after
    {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        clear: both;
    }

.footer
{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 25px;

    /*Addition*/
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

**Explanation:**
The `.footer` is fixed to the view port bottom, with a fix height. and spans the whole view port width.

the `.scollableContent` is absolutely positioned to span exactly all the space between the top of the view port, and the top of the footer. with automatic overflow that allow scrolling if the content is bigger than the available space.

inside the `.scollableContent` we have a simple block element for the header, that will span his content height. after him we have another block element for the content itself.
now we want the content to always stretch to the end of the container, regardless of the header height (so we can't apply it with a fixed height).

we achieve this using floating & clearing techniques.
we create a floating element before the `.scollableContent`, with no content (so it's invisible and doesn't really take any place at all) but with 100% height.

and at the end of the content div, we create a block with `clear` instruction.
now: this new block cannot be position in the same line with the floating element. so he has to be moved down, dragging the content div along with him.

**Et voilà!**

**EDIT:**
you're probably going to use this solution inside some existing Container in your website. (and not as the whole website layout).
I've updated the fiddle so that the content is enclosed within a container. that way it will be easier for you to port this solution to your working website.

here is the [**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/J9z9Q/1/)

Comment: only footer is scrollable, header slider and menu go up and down.

Comment: You contradict yourself. Maybe you meant that only the footer is **fixed**.  BTW: what about my solution?

Comment: It looks promising. Unfortunately I'll only be able to test it by the afternoon. Will let you know then obviously.

Comment: Just if you can explain, is it the `after` that 'fills' the `container` div?

Comment: Add explanation to my answer.

Comment: First of all thanks for the effort. Take a look at the [website](http://www.levhm.com/), my goal is to make everything dynamic so I will be able to make the CSS mobile-compatible. Correct me if I'm wrong. The problem with the existing site is 1) it gets screwed up on mobile 2) the footer goes nuts if height is too small.

Comment: Isn't there a way to copy a page including its CSS, JS and HTML and share?

Comment: emm.. something like JsFiddle? or JsBin?

Comment: I don't see where you implied my solution in your website. give me more concrete directions.. about 2) this is the behavior of `fixed` positioning. its relative to the view port. consider using `absolute` positioning instead.

Comment: I've updated my answer, now it will be easier for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    div {
        border: 3px solid black;
        height: 300px;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 25px;
    }
</style>
<div></div>
```

Comment: The CSS sets the element 25 pixels from the bottom of the page.

Comment: But what about its top? That's the whole issue here.

Comment: You're not giving us code to work with, so helping is stabbing in the dark. See my other answer above for tables.

Comment: Here's basically what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/NcpwC/2, I need the footer to be anchored to the bottom, header etc. docked to the element above, content - docked to bottom and to element above.

Comment: @Shimmy why don't you just remove `fixed` from _footer_?

Comment: @Vucko cuz the footer has to stick to the ground no matter what's going on above. `fixed` is mandatory on the footer.

Comment: he can be always at the end of the page, even without using `fixed` position. would that be good for you?